# Using json_normalize get error: If specifying a record_path, all elements of data should have the path

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, normalization

Trying to use json_normalize() and specify a record path of 'Job_Data', for a dict. that looks like this:

```
 myDict = [{'First_Name': 'Jack', 'Last_Name': 'Smith', 'Job_Data': [{'Company': 'Amazon'}, {'Hire_Date': '2011-04-01', 'Company': 'Target'}]}, 
     {'First_Name': 'Jill', 'Last_Name': 'Smith'}]
```

So I want my final output to look like this:

```
      First_Name    Last_Name    Hire_Date     Company
0     Jack          Smith        NaN           Amazon  
1     Jack          Smith        2011-04-01    Target
2     Jill          Smith        NaN           NaN
```

So my line of code is this:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data=myDict, meta=['First_Name', 'Last_Name'], record_path='Job_Data')
```

It's expected that not all of the data will have the Job_Data portion but I still want to try and normalize it. Any workarounds or other methods other than json_normalize to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be using `.explode()` + `.apply(pd.Series)`:

```py
myDict = [
    {
        "First_Name": "Jack",
        "Last_Name": "Smith",
        "Job_Data": [
            {"Company": "Amazon"},
            {"Hire_Date": "2011-04-01", "Company": "Target"},
        ],
    },
    {"First_Name": "Jill", "Last_Name": "Smith"},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(myDict).explode("Job_Data")
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("Job_Data").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1).drop(
    columns=0
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  First_Name Last_Name Company   Hire_Date
0       Jack     Smith  Amazon         NaN
0       Jack     Smith  Target  2011-04-01
1       Jill     Smith     NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Where does the `0` column come from?

Comment: @Nick `Jill Smith` doesn't have any Job_Data (`NaN`), so `.apply(pd.Series)` will create this default `0` column from it.